# Check new realm object is not saved yet

Tags: java, android, realm

Is anybody knows, how I can to check realm object is not saved to database yet?
I want to implement logic like in example below:

```
protected boolean prepareToSave(Product product, Realm realm) {
    // are we have enought space at storage?
    int productLimit = getLimit();
    if(
       /* product.isStoredInDB() && */ 
       realm.where(Product.class).count() >= productLimit)
       Toast.makeText(this, "Not enought space at storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
       // do another stuff
}
```

#### EDIT:

where:

```
public class Product extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey private long id;
    @Required private String title;
    private String note;
    private byte[] image;
    private byte[] thumbnail;

    private double count = Double.NaN;
    private double minimumCount = Double.NaN;

    // getters and setters
}
```

and method `getLimit()` returns only syntetic limitation of storage, not real SD card or internal storage capacity. This limitation is used for provide *In app purchases*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
Product p = getProduct()
if (!p.isManaged()) {
  // Object isn't saved in Realm 
}
```

But your code snippet seems to indicate that you want to check if the device has enough room to store your changes. There isn't really a way to check that for sure, since it will depend very much on the type of data you are going to store.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Christian. I have wrote an additional information to clarify my question. Can you answer: is method `createObject(Class<extends io.realm.RealmModel>, Object)` creates _managed_ or _unmanaged_ instance of `Product` class?